# Know if child class has implemented a parent method

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-2.x

I have a base class class X, and a child class Y which could reimplement or not a method from the base class X.

I pass the name of the child class as a variable to functions.

Inside those functions I need to test if that class passed has implemented or not some methods from it's base class.

(I can't use hasattr(childClassName.methodName) since it always returns True)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can a python base class tell whether a sub class has overriden its methods?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1776994/how-can-a-python-base-class-tell-whether-a-sub-class-has-overriden-its-methods)

Comment: I wonder why somebody is marking my question as duplicated, which is not as I said editing the question, and then voting down, which makes no sense.

Comment: Well because it is exactly the same with the marked question. Do you want me to delete my comment?

Comment: Is my question clear now? It is not a duplicate. In the other post they are asking if you can find that out INSIDE the child / base class. The answers could be similar, but the question is not the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use to compare:

```
 getattr(className, 'methodName') is getattr(className, 'method')
```

if `false`, the method was overridden