# How to check if a derived class has its own __init__ defined in Python?

Tags: python

```
class A:
  def __init__(self):
    pass

class B(A):
  pass

class C(A):
  def __init__(self):
    pass

print(hasattr(B, '__init__')) # True
print(hasattr(C, '__init__')) # True
```

How to check if derived class has its own `__init__` defined in Python? In the code above, only C has an `__init__` definition, but B also has an `__init__` attribute by inheritance. Is there a way to distinguish them?

Comment: What's a practical use case where that's important?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if an instance has overridden a superclass method or not in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44913773/check-if-an-instance-has-overridden-a-superclass-method-or-not-in-python)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `__dict__` of a class

```
class A:
  def __init__(self):
    pass

class B(A):
  pass

class C(A):
  def __init__(self):
    pass

print(C.__dict__.__contains__('__init__'))
print(B.__dict__.__contains__('__init__'))
```

This also works and looks cleaner.

```
print('__init__' in C.__dict__)
print('__init__' in B.__dict__)
```

Even more cleaner

```
print('__init__' in vars(C))
print('__init__' in vars(B))
```

Gives output

```
True
False
```

Comment: You can get the `__dict__` using the [`vars()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#vars) function. A bit cleaner and less "hacky"

Answer (score 2):

You could just compare the two:

```
B.__init__==A.__init__
True
C.__init__==A.__init__
False
```